# Can't read in files to perl module test?

Tags: perl, testing, readfile

I have Perl code to generate a has stored in two separate `.txt` files that I want to execute while testing my module, but I can't seem to read them into the test.

I've tried using the in-built file reader : `open FILE, 'file.txt'`,

`storable`: `retrieve('file')` where `file` is a storable file

and `File::Slurp`: `read_file('file.txt')`.

None of these work in the test file (`.t` format), but they do work in a normal `.pl` file in the same directory How can I make it work in the test? I would use the `__DATA__` option, but I have two files and they are already in the hash format so can just be read straight in.

Edit: my code -

```
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Slurp;

my $table1 = read_file('tab1.txt');
my $table2 = read_file('tab2.txt');
print Dumper($table1);
print Dumper($table2);
```

My output in test file:

```
$VAR1 = '';
$VAR1 = '';
```

and in the `test.pl` file `$VAR1` and `$VAR2` are exactly like the contents of the '.txt' file, as I would expect.

EDIT2:

Forgetting that there are hashes inside the files, that doesn't matter, I tried reading in a `test.txt` file I made with a random string in it and it came out with:

```
$VAR1 = 'Testing commit - part 12';
```

which seems to indicate that it is reading in files that are in a different location, so therefore doesn't find my files. I tried including the directory as a `lib` but that did not work.

Comment: "Hash" is a data structure, not a file format. You can't have "hashes stored in files". What does your file actually contain?

Comment: Saying it works in a `.t` but not a `.pl` is wrong. You've misdiagnosed the problem. It's something else, because Perl doesn't look at the extension at all. `.pl`, `.pm`, `.t`, `.foo` or no extension at all is all the same to Perl.

Comment: I'm only saying what I have seen... in each file I have one hash written in the expected way you would write a hash `'name' = { 'key1' => 'val1' };` format (except it is a lot bigger). They are hash references if that makes a difference. I get the hash as written outputted when I print from a read_in in a 'test.pl' file, but I get `''` when I try the same code in a 'test.t' file.

Comment: Share your code, please.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand the source of the problem if you provide the code you are using to read the "hash" files in.

Comment: You 2nd edit changes the focus of the question and makes my answer seem out of step. Do you want to focus on making hashes available to your code, or accessing the correct set of files?

Comment: accessing the files, the files could contain anything for all it matters, it is not finding the files, which is actually my question!

Comment: Why have I been downvoted? My problem is exactly as I have written and I have shown what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute Perl code. I'm guessing the code isn't a module (doesn't use `package`), so you'd use [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) instead of `use`/`require`.

Now you're left with locating a file relative to the location of the script. For that, there's [`$FindBin::RealBin`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin).

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/..";

our $VAR1;
do("file.txt")
   or die "Error executing file.txt: $@";

... $VAR1 ...
```

Be sure to return a true value from your file (by ending it with `1;`, for example).

Comment: I don't understand the use of `do` here. My text file doesn't contain code as such; just a data structure. Can you 'do' a data structure? 
My code is inside a test file which is testing a module's code, which I want to test by feeding in the data in these files so I can check the output.

Comment: You can even forget that it is a text file, I don't get any output if I put my data in a `storable` file and use that method to read it.

Comment: @bladepanthera: You said in a comment to the question that the data is stored in the file as `'name' = { 'key1' => 'val1' };` That _is_ code and it needs to be run to assign `{ key1 => 'val1' }` to the hash key `name`.

Comment: @DaveSherohman, that may be so but isn't actually my problem at the moment. It can't even seem to find the files I'm trying to open. Running the `do` comes back with the error.